# Is Adam Smith's "stock" an archaic version of "capital"?

Tags: economic-terms, adam-smith

In The Wealth of Nations, Adam Smith uses the word "stock" many times, but not with the meaning we ascribe to it today (supply of an asset, inventory). I take it that he refers to capital, as in a businessman who deploys capital into a business.

For instance:

> Such parts only of the produce of land can commonly be brought to market, of which the ordinary price is sufficient to replace the **stock** which must be employed in bringing them thither, together with its ordinary profits.

Is my assessment correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сельскохозяйственные продукты могут, в виде правила, поступать на
> рынок только в таком количестве, чтобы обычная цена их была достаточна
> для возмещения **капитала**, необходимого для доставления их туда, и для
> оплаты обычной прибыли.

This is the same place, but from Russian translation of the book. Here "stock" was translated as "капитал", which is a Russian word for "capital".

So, I think yes. It seems that you're right.

Comment: "капитал" and "capital" are the same word, just different alphabets

Comment: @Henry no "капитал" in Latin alphabet would be "kapital" not "capital"